# Google drive- Link video name.mp4

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api

How can I get a direct link to my video? I need a link video name.mp4

I can't embed the video from the disc into the site, the code given by google drive is not suitable for my site.

Google drive does not give a direct link to the video file, but

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bblAW_Aqy_Ef1fEQmvkn6n5qe0rQtcGD/view?usp=share_link.

This link doesn't work for me. also i tried to embed via

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bblAW_Aqy_Ef1fEQmvkn6n5qe0rQtcGD/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

This option works for me, but then everyone will know that the video was uploaded to google drive, it's dangerous for me. Also, if you insert a video through an iframe, you can follow the link to the page on Google Drive, this is bad.

Answer (score 0):

This depends grately on the language you are using but if you check the documetnation there are examples for this

The [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method returns a [file.resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) object

This contains a

> webContentLink string  A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in Google Drive.

Which will allow you to download the contents of the file.

The file.get method can also return the contentce of the file directly how this is done depends upon your programing language see: [manage-downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)

```
 $response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
      'alt' => 'media'));
 $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Anwser: How can I get a direct link to my video?

Google drive is a file storage api, not a file hosting api.  You are not going to get a link to a file for display via an iframe.  For that you should be using YouTube, YouTube is a video hosting platform they will host it for you there. What you are trying to do is out of scope for the google drive api.

Comment: YouTube NO!!!!!

Comment: Well Google drive is not for hosting files in this manner.   **The Google Drive API allows you to create apps that leverage Google Drive cloud storage.**   Its storage not hosting.